# ajax does'nt work inside table

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create an ajax inside table, but when I try to increment the `id="specificationName[' . $t . ']`, it does'nt work.
If I don't use [' . $t . '], it work but if I have 3 row it insert the 3 input only in the first row and not in each row.

Thank you

```
<script  src="http://boutique/javascript/tokeninput/jquery.tokeninput.min.js"></script>

  $products_specification_ajax = OSCOM::link('products_specification_ajax.php');
  $t = 0;
      while ($Qspecification->fetch()) {

       $QspecificationName = $this->app->db->prepare('select specification_id,
                                                             language_id,
                                                             name
                                                       from :table_specification_description
                                                       where  language_id = :language_id
                                                       and specification_id = :specification_id
                                                    ');
        $QspecificationName->bindInt(':language_id', $this->lang->getId());
        $QspecificationName->bindInt(':specification_id', $Qspecification->valueInt('specification_id'));
        $QspecificationName->execute();

  $content .= '<td>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#specificationName[' . $t . ']").tokenInput("' . $products_specification_ajax . '" ,
        {
          tokenLimit: 1,
          resultsLimit: 5,
          onResult: function (results) {
            $.each(results, function (index, value) {
              value.name = value.id + " " + value.name;
            });
            return results;
          }
        });
  });
</script>

' . HTML::inputField('specification_name[' . $t . ']', $specification_name, 'class="token-input" id="specificationName[' . $t . ']"') . '</td>';

$t++;
}
```

Comment: How do you mean "If I don't use [' . $t . '], it work"? I would also recommend a sample of the generated output with the expected output as well, which might help clarify the issue.

Comment: Is this HTML5? If it's HTML4, then `id="specificationName[' . $t . ']"` isn't legal, because of the `[` and `]` and possibly whatever the contents of `$t` are.

Comment: @GreatBigBore, I'm assuming it's PHP generating HTML. The opening <script> tag is out of place. Everything after that is pure PHP.

Comment: @CharlieHills If you move the script garbage out, it looks like he's trying to create a `<td>` with `id="specificationName[' . $t . ']"`. HTML4 isn't ok with those brackets.

Comment: @GreatBigBore, ahhh, gotcha. For me, I was focused on why $t might not be anything but 0, 1, 2, etc. It's not the most clearly-defined question I've seen.  :)

Comment: $t was the solution I found. [' . $t .'] doesn't work. $t is an increment